# How to draw a line of circles in android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I wanted to have a drawable resource that features a row of circles, with one of them in solid background similiar to this (refer to the row of circles at the bottom). I wanted to show an animation of it going from left to right, and having a drawable resource is the first step of achieving it.  How can I do that. thanks

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot, that seems to be a view that can be flipped sideways using a ViewPager. If that's the case, try using ViewPagerIndicator: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a TextView to which five strings (I have 5 steps) all composed with Unicode characters (\u26cb for the empty circle) and (\u26cf for the filled circle).

Like this (i stored them in my **res/values/arrays.xml** file):

```
<!-- Steps -->
<string-array name="steps">
    <item>\u25cf \u25cb \u25cb \u25cb \u25cb</item>
    <item>\u25cb \u25cf \u25cb \u25cb \u25cb</item>
    <item>\u25cb \u25cb \u25cf \u25cb \u25cb</item>
    <item>\u25cb \u25cb \u25cb \u25cf \u25cb</item>
    <item>\u25cb \u25cb \u25cb \u25cb \u25cf</item>
</string-array>
```

So, when the array is loaded, I can set the TextView's text easily basing upon the current step.

**[EDIT]**

As you probably know, Unicode characters ar not only "characters"... you can have some graphic icons (glyphs).
Among these, you find **circles** (filled and empty).

The first line in the array DRAWS a filled circle followed by 4 empty circles.
The second line DRAWS an empty circle, a filled circle and 3 empty circles, and so on.

To "animate" the row, just pass your TextView the next element in the array. as its text.

**[EDIT]**

Here's an emulated ldpi device screen showing **step 2 of 5** in the process.
This is **the second array element**.

[image]

Bottom part of the screen

**[EDIT]**

Why did I choose text instead of images?
Because  it is:
**light** (a ttf font is vectorial graphics),
**scalable** (I don't have to provide several PNGs for different screen resolutions),
**easy** (read the array once, and set a TextView's text accordingly),
**maintainable** (should I add or remove some steps, it's just a matter of modifying the string array accordingly)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't see any relevance to text and arrays here?. It's about rows of circles and making them animate

Comment: see my edited answer. I'm going to add one or more screenshot

Comment: THX. This is a great trick to learn

Comment: I'm glad to share some small tricks I learned myself ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator to add the titles or simple circles for each tab in your ViewPager.

The supplied sample code on [GitHub](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

You can also use the ViewPager and PageIndicator of [Greendroid library](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid)

Check out the [ViewPagerIndicator Tutorial](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-circle-style-example/)

Comment: I don't want to use ViewPagerIndicator. Any solution with using standard libraries?

Comment: Try out creating your own layout with the imageView's containing the dots and manage the selection accordingly.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to make an animation of it(sorry I haven't specified it in the first place). I can create a layout of them, simply, but I am not sure how to make them animated. since animationdrawable only takes drawable instead of layout. That's why I said I need a drawable in the first place

Answer (score 0):

you can take image of circle like in the above image and then set image in imageview place horizontally just like in the above image.

Comment: say I have a white icon and a grey icon. How can I make them into a xml drawable?

Comment: you can put their name in xml and then can fetch image from drawable folder.

Comment: I know that, but may not be in deep depths. can you show a sketch of it?