# How can I make an image slider like this image?

Tags: android

How can an Image slider [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwyhF.png) be achieved? I have an object of images, which I want to use for the image slider.

Comment: will this be a native app?

Answer (score 1):

I use to do that by using a TextView filled with Unicode characters.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857721/how-to-draw-a-line-of-circles-in-android/20862788#20862788), maybe it fits for you too.

Comment: Thank you! I was nearly becoming mad, when I was flashed by the idea of Unicode

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for `ViewPager`, this should be exactly what you are looking for. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score -1):

Using angular.js you can achieve this:

Getting started
Dependencies
This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on Twitter Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only required dependencies are:

AngularJS (minimal version 1.0.8)
Bootstrap CSS (tested with version 3.0.3)
Files to download
Build files for all directives are distributed in several flavours: minified for production usage, un-minified for development, with or without templates. All the options are described and can be downloaded from here.

Alternativelly, if you are only interested in a subset of directives, you can create your own build.

Whichever method you choose the good news that the overall size of a download is very small: <20kB for all directives (~5kB with gzip compression!)

Installation
As soon as you've got all the files downloaded and included in your page you just need to declare a dependency on the ui.bootstrap module:
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
You can fork one of the plunkers from this page to see a working example of what is described here.

CSS
Original Bootstrap's CSS depends on empty href attributes to style cursors for several components (pagination, tabs etc.). But in AngularJS adding empty href attributes to link tags will cause unwanted route changes. This is why we need to remove empty href attributes from directive templates and as a result styling is not applied correctly. The remedy is simple, just add the following styling to your application:

.nav, .pagination, .carousel a { cursor: pointer; }

Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
<h4>Single toggle</h4>
<pre>{{singleModel}}</pre>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">
    Single Toggle
</button>
<h4>Checkbox</h4>
<pre>{{checkModel}}</pre>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox>Right</button>
</div>
<h4>Radio</h4>
<pre>{{radioModel}}</pre>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Right'">Right</button>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var ButtonsCtrl = function ($scope) {

$scope.singleModel = 1;

$scope.radioModel = 'Middle';

$scope.checkModel = {
left: false,
middle: true,
right: false
};
};
```

Comment: @rajesh: angular can be implemented in android as well. he has not mentioned whether he's making a native or a 3rd party runtime supported app

Comment: I did not say that it can not be done. I specified what OP intended